# error when i want run android apps

Tags: android, eclipse

I get an error when it does I want my application to run on the Eclipse software, the images below represents the error and I hope to help me to find the solution.
Thank you

[image: app1]

[image: app1]

Comment: you really need to put more detail..

Comment: Start from your build path. Check whether every thing is set properly over there or not.

Comment: Look into the "Problems" view, to see what error your project has.

Comment: Why are you still using Eclipse and not Android Studio?

Comment: @jens 
Description Resource Path Location Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/mac/Desktop/Apps/skippy-ball-with-admob/Skippy Ball/libs/google-play-services_lib/bin/google-play-services_lib.jar' com.acitrus.skippyball  Build path Build Path Problem

Comment: @HamidS You reference a not existing lib.

Answer (score 0):

you should check if the google play service is added correctly , right click on a Java Project in the Package Explorer view and select the Properties menu item. On the left hand side tree select Java Build Path , then check if its added correctly or not .

after that clean and rebuild your project.
you can find the rebuild option under Project > Clean and then select the project you want to clean up. This will build your project and create a new bin folder.